# how to use multithreading to process multiple ids

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

i have a requirement where i have to process large number of ids from a csv,
i am using a threadpoolexecutor for doing this.

```
callRunnable cn=null;
Iterator it=crmCSVReader.iterator();
     cn= new callRunnable(it);
     BlockingQueue execQ= new LinkedBlockingDeque();
     execQ.add(cn);
     ThreadPoolExecutor exec= new ThreadPoolExecutor(2, 6, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, execQ);
```

and inside callRunnable.java i have run method implemented which takes this iterator instance initialised in callRunnable constructor.

```
  public void run()
{
if(it.hasNext())
        {
            csv=(CRMDataCSVModel)it.next();
            try {

                linenum++;
                log.info("Processing line number : [" + linenum
                        + "] and inputid : [" + csv.getInputid() + "]");
                System.out.println("Processing line number : [" + linenum
                        + "] and inputid : [" + csv.getInputid() + "] at time : " + Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
                MainClient.callPersist(csv.getInputid(), linenum);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                //log.error("Error in processing record for inputID", e);
            }

    }
```

But the problem is the iterator is read only once. and it gets stuck afterwards.

```
    Processing line number : [1] and inputid : [1067490351093320130621041031] at time : Thu Mar 26 06:50:44 IST 2015
Calling save to db ----calling thread--pool-1-thread-2
```

i think it might be because the iterator cannot be worked on simultaneously by multiple threads.
If it is so , what could be other alternative , i mean with whom can i replace this iterator instance.

Regards

Jayendra

Comment: How about iterating in threadexecutor code itself and passing CRMDataCSVModel to callrunnable!!

Comment: By the way, it is getting stuck because you are not actually moving to next record.. You need to use while/for loop to iterate records over iterator..

Answer (score 0):

It is getting stuck because you are not actually moving to next record.. You need to use while/for loop to iterate records over iterator..
Moreover, you may like iterate in executor code and pass CSV model object to runnable further processing.
Hope it helps.

Comment: i tried using while  before if(it.hasNext()), it runs fine  but in single threaded fashion  which fails the actual purpose.

Comment: Because you are passing whole CSV and creating only one thread..How about iterating in threadexecutor code itself and passing each CRMDataCSVModel to callrunnable!!